# Include different angular directives in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have several angular directives.
I want to include them in an accordion directive with an ng-repeat depending on the type.
I want it to be reusable, so I don't want the accordion to have knowledge of the type of directives it is rendering.
That's why I don't want to use an ng-switch directive inside the accordion.
Here is a very simplified demo. In reality those directives will have their own attributes for angular to compile.

```js
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
(function() {
  function Element1() {
    return {
      template: '<span>hello</span>',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true
    }
  }
  testApp.directive('elementOne', Element1);
}());

(function() {
  function Element2() {
    return {
      template: '<span>world</span>',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true
    }
  }
  testApp.directive('elementTwo', Element2);
}());

(function() {
  function Accordion() {
    return {
      template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="element in elements"><button>Toggle</button> Here should be the directive</li></ul>',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.elements = [{
          type: 1
        }, {
          type: 2
        }];
      }
    }
  }
  testApp.directive('elementAccordion', Accordion);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <element-accordion></element-accordion>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should `elements` be passed as attribute to the elementAccordion directive?

Comment: @hansmaad yes, I skipped it to simplify the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built something very similar a few weeks ago. I wanted to render a list of directives and select the type of directive based on the type of an element in an array (just like you). I tried to avoid `ngSwitch` because I've really many directives and want to add new directives without changing the `ngSwitch` statement every time. Let me show a simplified version of what I did. I hope this will help you to build your own version.

First, we need a global directory of element diretives and a helper function to register new directives. In my case, the helper function even **creates** the directive, but I'll skip this to keep it simple:

```
angular.module("app").provider('elementDirectory', function() {        
  return {
    elements: [],
    $get: function () {
      return {
        elements: this.elements
      }
    }
  };
});

function registerElementDirective(type, directiveName) {
  angular.module("app").config(['elementDirectoryProvider', function (elementDirectoryProvider) {
    elementDirectoryProvider.elements.push({
      type : type,
      directive : directiveName
    });
  }]);
}
```

Now, we can create some directives like this:

```
angular.module("app").directive('elementA', function() {
    return {
      template: '<span>ElementA</span>',
    }
});
registerElementDirective('A', 'element-a');
```

The most interesting part is a directive I called `elementSwitch`. It takes an array of elements and dynamically adds an `angular.element` for each element. Therefore, it creates prototypes for each element in the `elementDirectoy` and uses the `clone()` method on changes. (I think we could skip this part, it was an optimization).

```
angular.module('app').directive('elementSwitch', elementSwitch);    
elementSwitch.$inject = ['$compile', 'elementDirectory'];
function elementSwitch($compile, elementDirectory) {

  var prototypes = {};
  elementDirectory.elements.forEach(function (e) {
    var directiveElem = angular.element('<' + e.directive + '>');
    prototypes[e.type] = directiveElem;
  });

  return {
    scope: {
      elements: '=elementSwitch'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

      var childScopes = [];
      scope.$watchCollection('elements', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        childScopes.forEach(function (s) {
          s.$destroy();
        });
        childScopes = [];
        elem.empty();

        newValue.forEach(function (element, index) {
          var childScope = scope.$new();
          childScopes.push(childScope);
          var directiveElem = prototypes[element].clone();
          directiveElem.attr('element', '_elements[' + index + ']');
          $compile(directiveElem)(childScope);
          elem.append(directiveElem);
        });
        scope._elements = newValue;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is a complete example: https://codepen.io/hansmaad/pen/oLvRmj**

It doesn't do the same thing you want, but you should get an idea how you could achieve your goal.

Comment: very interesting approach.  
when you do:  
directiveElem.attr('element', '_elements[' + index + ']');  
is to copy what an ng-repeat does, right?  
It exposes an "element" property with the corresponding data from the array.

Comment: @airnan yes, it's similar to what `ngRepeat` does.